# Reffering to a specific page within a master page

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have a website which all inner pages are based on one master file.
I want to change the title font size of one page only not the whole pages that are using master page.
Is there a way to reference a page title or url using css or JavaScript?!
P.s I’m using Sitefinity CMS to build my website.

I appreciate any help of you all . 
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You can create a style sheet for that page only or add inline css to change the font.

Comment: Thanks VDWWD for replying. The inline style will target all page titles which I don’t want to do which I think also goes for the style sheet.

Comment: Not if you place it in the aspx of the page you want, you should not place it on the master.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a small javascript on the child page and it should overwrite your master page title.

```
document.title = "This is my title";
```

if you are using jQuery following code will help

```
$(function(){
    $(document).attr("title", "Another Title");
});
```

Comment: Thanks MCoder for your response. I guess this will change the title but not the font size of the title. What I really want is to change the font size of the title of couple of pages.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is possible. I believe one can only change the title text not the size (considering all browsers)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just use the following script to detect the page fron the url.                                                                                                                 $(function () {
      var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
      if (pathArray[1] == "Test")
      {
         $("h1").css("font-size", "5rem");
      }
});

Comment: Please test it with all browsers and it that works, post it as a solution.